# Haskell while to do while

Tags: haskell, do-while

I'm new to Haskell and I've been working on this for months now and I would be glad if someone would be willing to help me! I'm trying to get this program to work with a do while loop.

I have this while statement that can run this factorial program "x = 4; y = 1; while !(x == 0) do (y = y * x; x = x - 1)" that gives me the output "[("x",Integer 0),("y",Integer 24)]". The program goes like this:

```
whilestatement :: Parser Com
whilestatement = 
    do
        symbol "while"
        b <- bexpr
        symbol "do"
        s <- com
        return (While b s)
```

and the task is to make a do while statement that could run this factorial program "x =  4 ;  y = 1; do (y = y * x; x = x - 1) while !(x == 0)". What I did is that I just made some changes in the while statement. I changed this part just interchanged the symbol "do" and symbol "while":

```
whilestatement :: Parser Com
whilestatement = 
    do
        symbol "do"
        s <- com
        symbol "while"
        b <- bexpr
        return (While b s)
```

the program runs and gives the same output. But is this the right way to make a do while statement or can you help me how to make this while statement to do while statement. Thanks

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Please, can you remove all code that's not relevant to the question?

Comment: Just the same result but i'm not sure if the code is what do while is because the return still says While b s or is it already correct? @epsilonhalbe

Comment: sorry sir I removed irrelevant codes already @leftaroundabout

Answer (score 5):

A "do while" statement is slightly different than a "while" statement, in that it always executes the block once before checking the condition.

```
do BLOCK while (COND)
```

is the same as

```
BLOCK;
while (COND)  BLOCK
```

You could integrate this into your program by either returning an expression tree with a copy of the block sequenced before it (using `Seq`), or by adding a `DoWhile` case to the `Com` data type, and extending the `strans` function to handle it.

Also, you probably need to preserve the existing parsing of `while` when adding `do while` -- that is, instead of changing `whilestatement` to do what you want, add a new `dowhilestatement` parser and then add it to the `com` parser.

Comment: you mean this part? strans (While b c)    = code ++ [LOOP (strans_bool b, strans c)] I don't really understand. @ luqui

Comment: For the first option I mean `return (Seq s (While b s))` at the end of the parser instead of just `While b s` (which essentially makes do while a "macro")

Comment: Did you mean for the first pseudocode block to have `do while` rather than `while`? I suspect you did.

Comment: @dfeuer yes I did and gosh that must have been confusing.  Thanks

Comment: @luqui what should i change in the strans (While b c) = code ++ [LOOP (strans_bool b, strans c)] part when i use Dowhile (c b) ?